# Why does this generic code compile?

Tags: java, generics

```
<X> X foo(List<? super X> list)
{
    return null;
}
void test()
{
    List<Number> list = ...;
    String s1 = this.foo(list); // huh?
}
```

The last line doesn't make any sense, how could javac allow it?

Now, the `foo()` method doesn't make sense either; it must return null, there is no other value that can be returned in a type safe manner. Therefore the last line at runtime will not cause any problem: it assign a null to a String variable.

Still, statically, why does the last line compile? (**javac 1.6 u21 b06**)

Comment: I get `Type mismatch: cannot convert from Number to String` error.

Comment: what compilers do you guys use?

Comment: it fails on 1.6.0_22-b04

Comment: @Chris this suggests that it could be a compiler bug. if you make it an answer I could accept the answer.

Comment: >>> _foo() method doesn't make sense either_ Grammatically it is correct, also correct code is generated (i guess `null` is inlined). I would say that this is mode of a _static code analysis problem_ then compiler problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code won't compile with the next JDK version 1.6.0_22-b04. Error is:

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from Number to String

I guess your suggestion of a compiler bug may be true.

Comment: Interesting, so this compiler infers X=Number first. That's not compliant to spec either.

Comment: `$ javac -version  
javac 1.6.0_26`  still compiles (eclipse compiler does not compile)

Answer (score 4):

> what compilers do you guys use?

They are probably using eclipse, because it doesn't compile there. But it compiles from the command line. Eclipse had a bit different compilation mechanism in order to find out runtime problems sooner. Sometimes they are just warnings, in this case it is an error.

`List<? super X>` means that it can be `List<X>` or `List<Object>`. Therefore it can compile. On the other hand, it won't run, but *javac* does not care, it'll compile the code for you.

Answer (score 0):

Your code won't compile. The method's return type is `<X>`. When you are calling the method `foo` you are passing as the template parameter `Number`. Although you can assign a null to a String, but your method's signature becomes `Number foo()`, which means you are returning a `Number`. So the compiler will not allow you to assign a `Number` to a `String`.

Comment: It compiles with `javac 1.6 u21 b06`